# SQLAlchemy Conjunction with Parentheses

Tags: sqlalchemy, parentheses, on-clause

I am trying to produce the below sql in sqlalchemy core. I am not able to get the parentheses in the conjunction AND OR to appear.

```
select from member t1 
inner join member t2 
 on (
        (
          t1.first_name = t2.last_name and 
          t1.last_name = t2.first_name and 
          t1.dob = t2.dob
        )
        or (
             t1.last_name = t2.last_name and 
             t1.first_name = t2.first_name and 
             t1.dob = t2.dob
           )
    )
group by t2.id
```

The sqlalchemy core statement that I am using is:

```
selStmt = select([t1]).select_from(
    t1.join(
            t2, or_(
                    and_(
                         t1.c.first_name == t2.c.last_name,
                         t1.c.last_name == t2.c.first_name,
                         t1.c.dob == t2.c.dob
                         ),
                    and_(
                         t1.c.last_name == t2.c.last_name,
                         t1.c.first_name == t2.c.first_name,
                         t1.c.dob == t2.c.dob
                         )
                    )
            )
        ).group_by(t2.c.id)
```

The resulting sql code is:

```
SELECT t1
    FROM t1 
    JOIN t2 ON 
        t1.first_name = t2.last_name AND 
        t1.last_name = t2.first_name AND 
        t1.dob = t2.dob OR 
        t1.last_name = t2.last_name AND 
        t1.first_name = t2.first_name AND 
        t1.dob = t2.dob 
    GROUP BY t2.id
```

Since the parentheses are not included the logic is not correct. How do I get parentheses in conjunctions?

Comment: the logic is correct as `and` has higher priority than `or`.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the AND operation has higher precedence over OR. Therefore in my case the parentheses are not required.